# Как отобразить значение перменной из другого класса и функции в главный main

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Вопрос: здесь получить значение int b из функции "add", которая в 
            классе Class1 ? Как это сделать ?
            Class1.main();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

### //главный файл Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void main()
        {
            add();
        }
        public static void add()
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt16("5");
            int b = Convert.ToInt16("2");
            int sum = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt16(sum));
        }
    }
}
```

//Class1.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Class1
{
    public static int add()
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt16("5");
        int b = Convert.ToInt16("2");
        int sum = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt16(sum));
        return b;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int b = Class1.add();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```